# ¿Cómo realizar y graficar curvas ROC en R para clasificación muticlase?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Me encuentro realizando mi trabajo de grado, estoy estudiando los MODELOS DE MEZCLAS GAUSSIANAS (GMM), los cuales estoy usando para realizar clasificación, como estoy usando los GMM para clasificación, me es de interés mirar que tan preciso esta siendo el modelo como clasificador. Estoy trabajando con un conjunto de datos que tiene 5 etiquetas, las cuales hacen referencia a 5 clases de Arroz, dividi el conjunto de datos  en datos de prueba y datos de entrenamiento y corrí el GMM usando la función `Mclust`de la librería `mlcust`en `r`, me gustaría saber de que manera puedo realizar una curva ROC para este caso de multiclases, y calcular la AUC, vi que con una gráfica del tipo 1vstodos se podía, pero no detallan como, los ejemplos que se encuentran en otros lados no corren bien, y por ende es complicado ver como funciona

Adjunto un código de ejemplo del GMM usando iris, para este caso me gustaría ver como serian las curvas ROC

````
library(mclust)

Datos<-iris

set.seed(2022)

indices<-sample(1:nrow(Datos),size = floor(0.40*nrow(Datos)),replace = FALSE)
entreno<-Datos[indices,]
prueba<-Datos[-indices,]
table(Datos[indices,]$Species)
X<-Datos[indices,-5]
y <-Datos[indices,5]



GMM_iris<-Mclust(X,G=3)
summary(GMM_iris,parameters = TRUE)
table(y,GMM_iris$classification)

prediccion<-predict(GMM_iris,newdata = prueba[,-5])
table(Datos[-indices,]$Species,prediccion$classification)```
````

Answer (score 0):

La librería `pROC` tiene funciones que creo que te pueden ayudar mucho.

Retomo tu código a partir de la tabla de la matriz de confusión, ahí están los vectores de valores observados y predichos en los datos de prueba, que es lo que vamos a usar.

```
library(pROC) #para calcular y graficar ROC

# Primero calculamos el ROC para múltiples clases, los vectores son los
#mismo que usas para la matriz de confusión

multiclass.roc(Datos[-indices,]$Species, prediccion$classification) -> multiroc 

multiroc$auc  #Nos regresas en AUC multiclase.

#En ese mismo objeto (lista) están los roc de cada clase en la ubicación rocs

multiclass$rocs

#Y la función ggroc tiene un método para graficas múltiples curvas tomando
# una lista de rocs. Esa lista ya está hecha:

ggroc(multiclass$rocs)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Interpretar los resultados

Quizás estés familiarizado, pero para otra/a usuario/a podría servir, sobre todo porque, por casualidad o no, tus datos son un excelente ejemplo para distinguir error tipo 1 y error tipo 2.

Veamos la matriz de confusión:

```
              1  2  3
  setosa      0 29  0
  versicolor  4  0 24
  virginica  33  0  0
```

Es razonable asumir que el cluster 2 corresponde a setosa, el cluster 3 a versicolor y el cluster 1 a virginica. En los métodos de mixtura finita esto esto es materia de interpretación, pero en este caso es medio obvio.

### Para el cluster 2 (setosa)

Tienes una clasificación perfecta:

- No tiene errores del tipo 1, que sería en este caso clasificar a una setosa como otra especie. Las 29 setosas se clasificaron como setosas.
- No tiene errores del tipo 2, que en este caso sería clasificar a otra especie como una setosa. En la primera (setosa) fila de la tabla los cluster 1 y 3 tienen conteos 0.
- En "curva" verde del gráfico esto se refleja en especificidad y sensitividad perfectas: es un ángulo recto y el AUC para esta clase es 1.

### Para el cluster 3 (versicolor)

- No tiene error de tipo 1: todas las 24 versicolores se clasificaron como tales.
- Tienes error del tipo 2: 4 virgínicas se clasificaron como versicolores.
- En el gráfico la especificidad (relacionada con errores del tipo 1 o falsos negativos) tiene valor 1, es una recta horizontal. Eso porque no hay errores de tipo 1. Pero la sensibilidad (error tipo 2 o falsos positivos) ya no es perpendicular, porque tienes esos 4 falsos positivos.

### Para el cluster 1 (virginica)

- Tras el error de les cluster anterior: 4 virgínicas fueron mal clasificadas como versicolores.
- No tienes error del tipo 2: ninguna otra clase fue clasificada como virginica.
- En el gráfico especificidad (eje x, parte horizontal en esta curva) es perfecta (plana), pero la sensibilidad no es 1.

> PD1: es bastante complicado explicar esto y puedo haberme enredado o de plano equivocarme en la interpretación. Agradecería revisión de la respuesta, porque si algo de la interpretación está mal podría generar confusión.

> PD2: Uso cluster y clase de manera indistinta. En modelos de mixtura finita gaussianos (como este) se suele hablar de cluster, en modelos de mixtura finita para variables categóricas (como el análisis de clases latentes) se suele usar la palabra clases. En términos prácticos es lo mismo.